# Filtering arguments from Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arguments

The following code should take a given array and filter out all arguments that follow. For example the below code should return: [1, 1].

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args= [];
      args.push(arguments[0]);
  var realArgs = args[0];  
  var filteredArr=[];

  function removeIt (val){
     return val != ;
  }


  filteredArr= realArgs.filter(removeIt);

  return filteredArr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I can't figure out the filter function. Do I need to use Boolean somehow?

Comment: Wait... a function within a function actually works? Can you please specify what it is you need help with? what is the expected result and what is the given result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the arguments of the function you should use `arguments` not `args`. The filtering part is not straightforward because javascript still doesn't have a builtin function we can use, so we have to implement it by ourselves (that's the `includes` function).

```
function destroyer(arr) {

  var arr = arguments[0];  
  var toFilter = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    toFilter.push(arguments[i]);  

  function removeIt (arr, numsToFilter){
     var array = arr.slice(); // make sure to copy the array in order not to modify the original 
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (includes(numsToFilter, array[i])) {
            delete array[i]; 
        }     
      }
      return array;
  }

  function includes(arr, k) {
      for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if( arr[i] === k){
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }    

  return removeIt(arr, toFilter);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

[Running the code-example](http://labs.codecademy.com/D4nT/2#:workspace)

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to convert it to an array. We'll slice from the index 1 (skip the arr). Then you can [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `arr` array. On each iteration check if the item is in the `toRemove` array by using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Items that are in `toRemove` will be filtered out. Note - `Array#filter` returns a new array.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // convert all the arguments but arr into array
  var toRemove = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

  // filter the original array
  return arr.filter(function removeIt(val){
    // keep all vals that are not in the toRemove array
    return toRemove.indexOf(val) === -1;
  });
}

var result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

console.log(result);
```